# how would i scan each individual character

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a bar code program and I was curios as to how I would limit scan each character and then apply each bar code to each character and print it 
so like if user enters 54224 then output ":|:|::|::|::|:|::|:|:|::|" what is the best way to go about this.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Helloworld {

public static void main (String[]args){

    String input1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You should enter a number");
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt( input1);



    if (num1 == 1){
        System.out.print(":::||");
    }   
    if (num1 == 2){
        System.out.println("::|:|");
    }
    if (num1 == 3){
        System.out.println("::||:");
    }
    if (num1 == 4){
        System.out.println(":|::|");
    }
    if (num1 == 5){
        System.out.println(":|:|:");
    }
    if (num1 == 6){
        System.out.println(":||:::");
    }
    if (num1 == 7){
        System.out.println("|:::|");
    }
    if (num1 == 8){
        System.out.println("|::|:");
    }
    if (num1 == 9){
        System.out.println("|:|::");
    }
    if (num1 == 0){
        System.out.println("||:::");
    }


}

}
```

Comment: read it all in, then split the number into each digit

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: `charAt`? or use divide/modulo to get at decimal digits in `int`.

Comment: @GhostCat I'd agree with you but the majority does not. And SO the company most emphatically does not. See Meta for countless examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compact your code like this:

```
List<String> codes = Arrays.asList ("||:::", "::|:|", "::||:", ":|::|", ":|:|:", ":||:::", "|:::|", "|::|:", "|:|::");
```

And call it with a recursive method:

```
String num2code (int n) {
    return (n > 0) ? num2code (n/10) + codes.get (n % 10) : "";
}

-> num2code (54170)
|  Expression value is: ":||::::|:|:::|:||::|:||:::"
|    assigned to temporary variable $4 of type String
```

The possible size might be increased if you like with longs.

A single 0 with not yield output, and each leading 0 is lost, so if you have to deal with such input, you have to change to a character based approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Switch` to choose the pattern for every digit, then insert it into the beginning of a `StringBuilder` and return the `String` from it.

To get each digit, you can use `modulo` operator and then divide by `10`, you'll get the number in reverse order and that's why you need to prepend every pattern of each digit to the beginning of the `StringBuilder`

For example:

```
public class BarCodeTranslator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertInputToBarCode(54224));
    }

    private static String convertInputToBarCode(int input) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String pattern = "";
        do {
            int mod = input % 10;

            switch (mod) {
                case 1:
                    pattern = ":::||";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pattern = "::|:|";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pattern = "::||:";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pattern = ":|::|";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pattern = ":|:|:";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pattern = ":||:::";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    pattern = "|:::|";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    pattern = "|::|:";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    pattern = "|:|::";
                    break;
                default: //0 digit
                    pattern = "||:::";
                    break;
            }

            sb.insert(0, pattern);
            input /= 10;
        } while (input != 0);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
:|:|::|::|::|:|::|:|:|::|
```